# Is this a bug of `Series.plot` in pandas 0.17?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I always use `ser.plot(xticks=range(0, len(ser), step), ..)` to plot figures with specified xticks. But it doesn't work anymore in pandas 0.17 when the `Series` with labels. Here are the codes:

```
In [1]: from numpy import random as rnd 
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '0.17.0'
In [4]: %matplotlib inline
In [5]: rnd.seed(123)
In [6]: ser = pd.Series(rnd.randn(73).cumsum(), index=['P%02d' % i for i in range(73)])
In [7]: ser.plot(figsize=(9, 6), rot=60, title='Figure without xticks')
Out[7]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x8370198
```

[image]

```
In [8]ser.plot(figsize=(9, 6), xticks=list(range(0, 73, 6)), rot=60, title='Figure with xticks')
Out[8]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x83e9940>
```

[image]

And the same code in pandas 0.16:

```
In [1]: from numpy import random as rnd
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '0.16.0'
In [4]: %matplotlib inline
In [5]: rnd.seed(123)
In [6]: ser = pd.Series(rnd.randn(73).cumsum(), index=['P%02d' % i for i in range(73)])
In [8]: ser.plot(figsize=(9, 6), xticks=list(range(0, 73, 6)), rot=60, title='Figure with xticks')
Out[8]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xbbf19b0>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a regression in 0.17.0, and will be fixed in 0.17.1 (see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11531).

If you need a workaround for now (until 0.17.1 is released or to prevent that you need to downgrade), you can:

- adjust the ticklabels manually after creating the plot with:

  ```
  ax.set_xticklabels(['P%02d' % i for i in ax.get_xticks()])
  ```
- or apply the patch in the pandas code (see the link above, it's only a one line change)